# How to create a lead in salesforce by using journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

How to create  a lead and update activity  in salesforce by using journey builder

Comment: What is initiating this process? A form fill on a website? Is the form built in Marketing Cloud? If not, what form building tool or is it custom built?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have the Marketing Cloud connector correctly installed/integrated between you clouds.

Then in your Journey - you should simply be able to drop a 'Lead' activity into your Journey Canvas from where you can configure to create or update a lead object.

[image: Drop the Lead Activity into the Canvas]

When you are configuring the Lead Activity - you can choose to Create a New Lead

[image: Create a New Lead]

EDIT :
You may wish to rethink your solution as it's unclear what exactly you are wanting to achieve. If the contact record doesn't exist in the lead Object, where are you getting the contact from to begin with?

Consider on your Journey Entry, a query to select contacts for the journey and check then if the contact exist. Alternatively use the Salesforce Lead Activity in Marketing Cloud to `Find and Update` the Lead Object and set `Create new record` When no records are found :

[image]

Comment: How to check this records is exist or not in salesforce in journey builder

Comment: hi , my question is - If the Requestor doesn’t already have a record in Salesforce, create a new lead record, and update with Invite Request. This should include all details (full contact info, date/time, etc) being provided. can we do this by using journey builder ?